# What port is this, and can I create a cable for it?

Tags: gpio

I have a [Elo Backpack 4](https://www.elotouch.co.uk/accessories-backpack-4.html) and I want to make use of the GPIO port to open a cash drawer via RJ11.

There is information regarding the GPIO in the [Backpack user guide](https://docs.elotouch.com/UM600694.pdf). It mentions that [this cable](https://myelo.elotouch.com/support/s/article/E211544-GPIO-Cable-Information) can be used, but I'm finding it hard to source for a reasonable price.

My question is, is the port using a standard plug that I can source more easily? I was wondering if it was some sort of JST but I'm not convinced regarding the dimensions. If so, would it be feasible to create my own cable?

Comment: For anyone to understand your question they'd have to follow two or three links and the question will be useless to future readers if the links die. Add the required images into your question and credit the owners / creators with a link.

Comment: If the cable exists and has technical drawings, why would anyone doubt if it is feasible or not? And which price do you consider to be reasonable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link to the cable has a drawing that identifies the connector:

[image]

It is a "1.25T-1-5Y" or "11251h00-5P"

The correct terminals are also listed.

You could easily re-create this cable yourself very cheaply.

Comment: The OP wants us to find a replacement for 11251h00-5P-HF housing (made by JCTC https://jctc.com.cn/en-us/product-detail/7815.html ) for him.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I was to make the cable myself, what tools and materials would you recommend? I have no experience doing this so any guidance is helpful!

Comment: All you need is the housing and the terminals.  The crimpers for those can be expensive, but either generic crimpers or even needle-nose pliers can work fine in a pinch for a one-off.